# How to use $apply in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

> ```
> > angular.min.js:107 Error: [$rootScope:inprog]
> > http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
> >     at angular.min.js:6
> >     at t (angular.min.js:126)
> >     at r.$apply (angular.min.js:133)
> >     at b.$scope.nextStep (equipment_control_sheet.js:97)
> >     at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:213), <anonymous>:4:215)
> >     at e (angular.min.js:254)
> >     at b.$eval (angular.min.js:133)
> >     at b.$apply (angular.min.js:134)
> >     at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:254)
> >     at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
> ```

This is what I am getting an error when I am trying to call $scope.$apply() method.

Is there any specific way to call it?

Right now I am calling it after removing an element to refresh scope contents as even after removing that element, its entry with null/undefined value still exists.

Current $scope entry which I have removed is coming as follows,

```
> caliber2 : yg $$debounceViewValueCommit : ƒ (b)
> $$lastCommittedViewValue : undefined $$parentForm : Fd {$error: {…},
> $$success: {…}, $pending: undefined, $name: "ECSAdd", $dirty: false,
> …} $$parseAndValidate : ƒ () $$rawModelValue : undefined
> $$runValidators : ƒ (a,b,c) $$setOptions : ƒ (a) $$success :
> {maxlength: true} $$writeModelToScope : ƒ () $asyncValidators : {}
> $commitViewValue : ƒ () $dirty : false $error : {required: true}
> $formatters : [ƒ] $invalid : true $isEmpty : ƒ (a) $modelValue :
> undefined $name : "caliber2" $options : null $parsers : [] $pending :
> undefined $pristine : true $render : ƒ () $rollbackViewValue : ƒ ()
> $setDirty : ƒ () $setPristine : ƒ () $setTouched : ƒ () $setUntouched
> : ƒ () $setValidity : ƒ (a,e,f) $setViewValue : ƒ (a,b) $touched :
> false $untouched : true $valid : false $validate : ƒ () $validators :
> {required: ƒ, maxlength: ƒ} $viewChangeListeners : [] $viewValue :
> undefined
> __proto__ : Object
```

This is my remove row code,

```
$scope.removeRow = function(i) {
    temp = [];
    $.each($("tr[data-index='" + i + "']").find("td").find("select, input"), function(i,j){
        var nm = $(this).attr("name");
        temp.push(nm);

        // $scope.form[nm].$destroy();
        // delete $scope.form[nm];
        $scope.form[nm] = "";
        // console.log($scope.form);
    });
    $("tr[data-index='" + i + "']").remove();
    // var oldList = $scope.form;
    // $scope.items = {};
    // angular.forEach(oldList, function(x,j) {
    //     if(temp.indexOf(j) == -1){
    //         $scope.items[j] = x;
    //     }
    // });
    // $scope.form = $scope.items;
    // var oldList = $scope.ECSAdd;
    // $scope.items = {};
    // angular.forEach(oldList, function(x,j) {
    //     if(temp.indexOf(j) == -1){
    //         $scope.items[j] = x;
    //     }
    // });
    // $scope.ECSAdd = $scope.items;

     // $timeout(function(){ $scope.$digest();$scope.$apply(); });


}
```

And here is the test case,

I have one row, I added one new row and then removed the added row(add more functionality).

Every element has validation in every row.

But what I am facing is, it's unable to remove validation for elements inside the row which are removed.

Am I clear?

Comment: You can wait a digest with: `$timeout(function(){
        $scope.$apply();
    });` So the rootScope isnt "inprog"

Comment: Apply worked, but even after removing element, $invalid is still true and its showing undefined value for removed element, do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: @rahulsm some relevant code will be helpful.

Comment: "You can wait a digest with $timeout".. $timeout will end up as the last argument in the callstack and therefore executed after the digestloop is completed.

Comment: As you can see in my commented code(last line) `$timeout(function(){ $scope.$digest();$scope.$apply(); });` I added this, but still no luck